# Windows Server 2019: Can't add locations to index for windows search

Tags: windows-server-2019, search-server, indexing-service

i'm obviously far too stupid, but maybe someone has mercy ;-)

System: Windows Server 2019 Standard DC

Tested Users: administrator

Problem: Windows search Server index only includes one useless location: Internet Explorer History. As a result there are 0 indexed files [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga9xA.jpg).

And i can't add any other location in indexing oprions -> more, because the show all locations button is greyed out [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7SI4.jpg).

What have i have tried so far:

```
Windows index service troubleshooter
Rebuild index
Move Index to different folder
Uninstall / Reinstall Windows Search feature
Try with new administrative user
and a lot more..
```

ANY SUGGESTIONS APPRECIATED.....

Thanks a lot !